# Jquery colorbox display location

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am using colorbox to display html content errors.

I need to display it at location of link click. Is there any way to set position of it to the same of near of that link?

---

`CODE`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
        setColorbox();
  });

  //This will set colorbox ids.
  function setColorbox(){
        var a = $('#requestText').val();

        if($("#request").length){
             $("#request").colorbox({html:a, maxHeight:"65%",opacity:0.5});
        }

  }
```

and

```
    <div><b>Request Text :</b></div>
    <h:panelGroup style="dispaly:block" rendered="#{refillRenewalRequestBackingBean.str2!=''}">
    <a href="#" id="request">View-Text</a>
    <input type="hidden" id="requestText" value="<h:outputText value="#{refillRenewalRequestBackingBean.str2}"/>" />
```

I am using this kind of script.
Now I need to display colorbox on same place where `href` `view-Text` is clicked. 
**Is it possible?**

Comment: Yes there is. If you want to know how it applies to your code then you need to show some.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery colorbox : How can I change the position of the colorbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353577/jquery-colorbox-how-can-i-change-the-position-of-the-colorbox)

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... give me a second for fatch it from lot of code...